# UISplitViewController is only available for iPad Applications [iOS 7.1]

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller, ios7.1

I just updated XCode 5 with 7.1 and i can't build anymore because of the next failure

**UISplitviewController is only available for iPad applications**

I have an universal app. The App version starts from 6.0 till 7.0. I tried everything from architecture to schemes and Main interface settings but nothing works. Does anyone have this same problem with the new iOS SDK 7.1 ?

Comment: UISplitviewController was always only for ipad, you can read it in apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: it always worked, but since i updated xcode it gives me this error message..

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried to do all of you mentioned (created Universal App via XCode5.1 and added UISplitViewController) and everything works well.

Check, maybe you have some option in LLVM 5.1 settings (Target->Build Settings) like Treat Warnigns as Erroros, etc.

[image]

Comment: No it still gives me the same error "Class Unavailable". I have a XCode 5.0 with the same project and it builds with no problems. I think it's within the iOS SDK 7.1. I even saw in the component table in the storyboards that there is no UISplitViewController is available in the storyboards

Comment: Hm, seems to be you are trying to use UISplitViewController in storyboard with device family "iPhone". I'm having 2 storyboards: Storyboard~iphone and Storyboard~ipad. UISplitViewController is present in iPad and absent in iPhone one.

Comment: you should put your solution as an answer.